# evil-surround: change and delete not working with all surroundings

Tags: evil

I'm using GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (GUI version) on Mac OS X 10.11.1 with Evil mode and installed [`evil-surround`](https://github.com/timcharper/evil-surround) through the built-in package manager of Emacs.

Now, I can add all surroundings, for example, surround a word by `/` with `viwS/`.

However, changing and deleting surroundings works only with certain types of surroundings, for example, `"`, `'`, `)`, `]`, but not with `/`, `*`, `=` (which are used in org-mode).

If I move the cursor, for example, on the text `/word/`, and type `ds/`, then after typing `ds` the word `delete` appears in the minibuffer, but then upon typing `/` the minibuffer is emptied, but nothing changes in the surrounded word, i.e. the `/` are still there.

Does anyone know how to fix this, i.e. allow surroundings like `/`, `*`, `=` to work properly?

Comment: I generally consider Stackexchange the wrong place for bug reports, with the exception of projects that decided to use it as their user support "forum".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing the packages [`embrace`](https://github.com/cute-jumper/embrace.el) and [`evil-embrace`](https://github.com/cute-jumper/evil-embrace.el) fixes the problem.  After that you must define new pairs with `embrace`.  I have

```
(use-package embrace
    :ensure embrace)
(use-package evil-embrace
    :ensure evil-embrace)
(evil-embrace-enable-evil-surround-integration)
(setq evil-embrace-show-help-p nil)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
    (lambda ()
        (embrace-add-pair ?a "`" "'")
        (embrace-add-pair ?e "\\emph{" "}")))
```

Comment: Great. To add the common org-mode surrounding pairs to org-mode, it's enough to add the line `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'embrace-org-mode-hook)`.